# android activity with list loaded from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Say I have main activity that contains a list (never mind if it is a ListView or RecyclerView). Each time the activity is created it has in its onResume method a query for data from parse. The thing is the parse query I use calls findInBackground method so my list in main activity is always zero since by the the time the activity is constructed the query hasn't finish yet. when I use find (and not find in background) I see in android studio logcat a sentence like the follwoing : "to many operation on main thread".

What do u think I should do?
Thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansive operations like this should be done on a seperate thread in the background, so the main (animation) thread will not be blocked, causing your app to lag. The `findInBackground()` method will do the same as `find()`, but on a different thread 'in the background'. When the job is done, it will call the `FindCallback` and pass the result so you can update your list.

Untill this is done you could show a intermediate `ProgressBar` in front of your empty list to indicate that the data is loading.